# How to swap two cells of two different tables view?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm stuck with this problem: 
I'm using this code to swap two cells of the same table view. I want to ask you how I should edit this code to swap two cells of two different table view in the same controller? I think that there isn't much to edit but I can't do on my own... thank you all.

```
@objc func onLongPressGestureDone(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let locationInView = sender.location(in: tableViewDone)
    let indexPath = tableViewDone.indexPathForRow(at: locationInView)

    if sender.state == .began {
        if indexPath != nil {
            initialIndexPathDone = indexPath
            let cell = tableViewDone.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)
            cellSnapshotDone = snapshotOfCellDone(inputView: cell!)
            var center = cell?.center
            cellSnapshotDone?.center = center!
            cellSnapshotDone?.alpha = 0.0
            tableViewDone.addSubview(cellSnapshotDone!)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                center?.y = locationInView.y
                self.cellSnapshotDone?.center = center!
                self.cellSnapshotDone?.transform = (self.cellSnapshotDone?.transform.scaledBy(x: 1.05, y: 1.05))!
                self.cellSnapshotDone?.alpha = 0.99
                cell?.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                if finished {
                    cell?.isHidden = true
                }
            })
        }
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        var center = cellSnapshotDone?.center
        center?.y = locationInView.y
        cellSnapshotDone?.center = center!

        if ((indexPath != nil) && (indexPath != initialIndexPathDone)) {
            progetto.done.swapAt(indexPath!.row, initialIndexPathDone!.row)
            tableViewDone.moveRow(at: initialIndexPathDone!, to: indexPath!)
            initialIndexPathDone = indexPath
        }
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        let cell = tableViewDone.cellForRow(at: initialIndexPathDone!)
        cell?.isHidden = false
        cell?.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.cellSnapshotDone?.center = (cell?.center)!
            self.cellSnapshotDone?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.cellSnapshotDone?.alpha = 0.0
            cell?.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            if finished {
                self.initialIndexPathDone = nil
                self.cellSnapshotDone?.removeFromSuperview()
                self.cellSnapshotDone = nil
            }
        })
    }
}

func snapshotOfCellDone(inputView: UIView) -> UIView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    inputView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let cellSnapshotDone = UIImageView(image: image)
    cellSnapshotDone.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cellSnapshotDone.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0
    cellSnapshotDone.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5.0, height: 0.0)
    cellSnapshotDone.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    cellSnapshotDone.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
    return cellSnapshotDone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easier with the `moveRow(at:to:)` function:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.moveRow(at: firstIndexPath, to: secondIndexPath)
tableView.moveRow(at: secondIndexPath, to: firstIndexPath)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: And can I do it also with two different tables view?

Comment: @AndreaCulot this may help you: http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-drag-and-drop-between-uitableviews/